# Server error after log in

Tags: login, fatal-error

Hello everyone when I am going to the admin Area and fill the user name and password and than click on login button.

The login page is taking too long and after that I am getting below error. Please see the screenshot:

[image]

After that I do some research and checked the file permission and found that all the files has only 605 permission.

I have change all the files permission `chmod -R 755`.

But still same issue.

Please out me this issue if anyone faced the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

permission for files should be `644` and permissions for folders should be `755`

Try changing permissions accordingly and see of anything changes.

Comment: this will for whole wordpress website like wp-include files, and their folders?

Comment: yes. for all the files and folders

Comment: Could you please provide me the command line for that? I have `SSH root` access.

Comment: I normally use `find /var/www/mySite/ -type f -print -exec chmod 644 {} \;` and `find /var/www/mySite/ -type d -print -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

Comment: My server path '/clickandbuilds/Genexjaipur/' and I have run this command `find clickandbuilds/Genexjaipur/* -type f -print -exec 644 {} \;
`, but I am getting the `No Such file or directory`.

Comment: Make sure the path is correct & no need of * at the end.

Comment: I have tried with this `find clickandbuilds/Genexjaipur/ -type -f -print -exec chdmod 644 {} \;` and getting the `find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter` .

Comment: you have a syntax errror in command. -f should be just f

Comment: @Abdule Many thanks, I have tried with this find clickandbuilds/Genexjaipur/ -type f -print -exec chdmod 644 {} \; and getting the find: `chmod` No Such file or directory .

Comment: again spelling mistake in another word! `chmod`

Comment: I done the permission but the issue is solved yet.. What cause this issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57195/discussion-between-abdul-awal-and-magedev0688).